# Vectorizing sum expression

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given two vectors $ \mathbf{\nu} = (\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k)$ and $\mathbf{\gamma} = (\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_k)$, and this expression resulting in a new vector:

$$ \mu_j = \sum_{i=1}^{j} \nu_i \gamma_{j-i+1} $$

Is there a way I can rewrite this expression with matrix / vector multiplication?

Purpose: Essentially I need this in a "vectorized" format, as for cycles in the software (theano) I'm using can be expensive.

Comment: When you refer to the "vector $\nu_i$", are you saying that for each $i = 1,\dots,k$: $\nu_i$ is a vector, or are you saying that we have a vector whose entries are $(\nu_1,\dots,\nu_k)$? If you mean the first, then how do you define the product $\nu_i \gamma_{j-i+1}$ of two vectors?

Comment: If you meant the first of these, then the more standard way of communicating this is to say that you have two vectors: $\nu$, which is given by $(\nu_1,\dots,\nu_k)$, and $\gamma$, which is given by $\gamma = (\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k)$.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nu,\gamma$ denote the column-vectors $\nu = (\nu_1,\dots,\nu_k)$, $\gamma = (\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k)$.  Your expression for $\mu_j$ can be written as
$$
\mu_j = \pmatrix{\gamma_j & \cdots & \gamma_1 &  0 & \cdots & 0}\pmatrix{\nu_1 & \cdots & \nu_k}^T.
$$
With that, we find that
$$
\mu = \pmatrix{\mu_1\\ \mu_2 \\ \vdots \\ \mu_k} = 
\pmatrix{\gamma_1\\
\gamma_2 & \gamma_1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots\\
\gamma_k & \cdots & \gamma_2 & \gamma_1} \pmatrix{\nu_1\\ \nu_2 \\ \vdots \\ \nu_k} = T_\gamma \nu.
$$
In the (lower triangular and [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix)) matrix $T_{\gamma}$, the blank entries are all $0$.

We could also exchange the roles of $\nu$ and $\gamma$ in the above formula.